# Sanitizing pdf output for inclusion in LaTeX

Tags: graphics

I wish to include a pdf graphic generated by a third-party scientific code in a LaTeX file. The problem: the pdf graphic has a bounding box issue. When the pdf graphic is opened---along with the resulting LaTeX-generated pdf which includes it---I get the following popup error in Acrobat Reader: "The font XYZ contains a bad /BBox"

I don't control the third-party software that generates this image and thus can't generate a vector graphic from it besides using its built-in capabilities. Yes, I could take a screenshot but this needs to be vector-quality.

Is there a way to sanitize such a pdf graphic to remove the bounding box issue before including in LaTeX?

Comment: You could put it through some PDF tool like Ghostscript or `pdftk`. The latter claims to be able to fix issues.

Comment: As it seems you don't need an automatic process, did you try opening the original PDF in inkscape and exporting it again, probably best using PDF version 1.4 instead of 1.5?

Comment: @Christian Inkscape performed the job perfectly. Many thanks.

Comment: I'll make it an answer then I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the PDF that is to be embedded in [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) and save it again, choosing PDF as the output format. In the dialog window that then pops up, choose PDF version 1.4.